# Foreign key referencing its own table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Can any one explain why the following doesn't work on MySql (gives Syntax error currently):

```
create table manager
(
    employee_name varchar(20) not null,
    manager_name varchar(20) not null, 
    primary key employee_name, 
    foreign key (manager_name) references manager 
    on delete cascade
)
```

also, assuming it did work, what would happen when a tuple in the relation manager is deleted?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the syntax would be,

```
create table manager 
( 
    employee_name varchar(20) not null, 
    manager_name varchar(20) null, 
    CONSTRAINT tb_pk primary key (employee_name), 
    CONSTRAINT tb_fk foreign key (manager_name) 
          references manager (employee_name) on delete cascade 
)
```

**QUESTIONS:** assuming it did work, what would happen when a tuple in the relation manager is deleted?

**ANSWER:** all the child entries will also be deleted.

Comment: what about the fact that this table is referencing itself, will DB try to delete the entry twice?

Comment: it will delete manager reference (all foreign key references) and then it will delete the employee record.  But in an ideal business case, you would not want to do cascade delete.  My suggestion is that, you will have to replace all the employees with the other manager name and then delete this record.  So this deletion should be taken care on your business logic.